NextJS 12 version Route Issue
I'm working with NextJS 12 version. When I select menus in sidebar, page reloading doesn't work well. I've implemented using next-link. In some cases, I selected a menu but the page does not reload.
e.x: I'm going to move <home> tab => <explore> tab but full page reloaded. In this case, this is inspect console outpus: [Fast Refresh] rebuilding] building
<Link

  href={href}
  className='w-full'
>
  <a>
    <div
      className={`${StyleClasses} mb-2 flex cursor-pointer items-center justify-center space-x-3 rounded-[14px] py-[15px] pl-3 text-white transition-all duration-100 hover:bg-[#252525] ${
        sideBarMenuText ? 'w-full' : 'xl:w-[256px] '
      } xl:justify-start ${active && 'bg-[#252525]'} ${
        isMore && text === 'More' && 'bg-[#252525]'
      }`}
      target={changeTab === 'CreatorStudioActive' ? '_blank' : '_self'}
    >
      {active ? (
        <IconActive />
      ) : (
        <Icon
          strokeclasses={`stroke-[#515151] transition duration-100`}
        />
      )}
      <div className='flex flex-col'>
        <span
          className={`${
            active ? 'font-open-sans-semi-bold' : ' font-open-sans'
          } ${sideBarMenuText} hidden text-[18px] leading-6 text-white xl:inline`}
        >
          {text}
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</Link>

I'd like to solve this issue.

it is not clear what you are asking

Okay, I'll explain more detail.
I'm going to move  tab =>  tab but now I can't more tab. Instead full page reloaded. In this case, this is inspect console outpus: [Fast Refresh] rebuilding] building

Hi Yilmaz, thanks for your response. This is urgent issue for me.

Could you remove the tag inside the Link? It would be best if you did not use an a tag inside the Link component as it can cause issues with client-side navigation. Instead, use the passHref prop on the Link component and wrap the div with the Link component directly.
<Link href={href} passHref>
  <div
    className={`${StyleClasses} mb-2 flex cursor-pointer items-center justify-center space-x-3 rounded-[14px] py-[15px] pl-3 text-white transition-all duration-100 hover:bg-[#252525] ${
      sideBarMenuText ? 'w-full' : 'xl:w-[256px] '
    } xl:justify-start ${active && 'bg-[#252525]'} ${
      isMore && text === 'More' && 'bg-[#252525]'
    }`}
    target={changeTab === 'CreatorStudioActive' ? '_blank' : '_self'}
  >
    {active ? (
      <IconActive />
    ) : (
      <Icon strokeclasses={`stroke-[#515151] transition duration-100`} />
    )}
    <div className='flex flex-col'>
      <span
        className={`${
          active ? 'font-open-sans-semi-bold' : ' font-open-sans'
        } ${sideBarMenuText} hidden text-[18px] leading-6 text-white xl:inline`}
      >
        {text}
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</Link>

